Jira status / column API issue
I am trying to create a custom column (like "In Testing") in Jira using the Jira API, but I am unable to find the appropriate API endpoint or documentation for this task.
Currently, I am using the Kanban template in Jira, which includes the default columns: "To Do", "In Progress", and "Done". However, I want to add additional columns to better fit my workflow.
What I have tried:
I have reviewed the Jira REST API documentation, but I could not find any endpoint related to creating or modifying columns in a board.
I attempted to use the existing board and project APIs to see if there was an option to add columns, but without success.
I have searched through various forums and Stack Overflow posts, but none of the solutions provided a clear method to achieve this.
Question:
Does anyone know the specific API endpoint or method to create a custom column in a Jira board using the Jira API? Any example or guidance would be greatly appreciated.


I have reviewed the Jira REST API documentation, but I could not find
any endpoint related to creating or modifying columns in a board.

Congratulations! You have read the documentation correctly and found that there are indeed no Jira Software REST API endpoints for creating or managing Columns on Boards. All you can do is get the Columns on a Board via the Get Configuration endpoint, and nothing more.
Just Google 'Jira Software REST API manage Board Columns' to find all the other times others have asked the same question.
